# How can I copy the recent copy of my database backup from the website to the development machine?

Tags: windows, backup, mysql

I finally have daily mysql backups working on my 3 shared servers hosting 6 websites.  They are organized in folders such as

```
backup\2022-08-20\
backup\2022-08-21\
```

where each folder has that days backup of each database (2 to 3 of them).  I have created them using `mysqldump` to get started.

Now I want to copy over the latest backup to my development machine, at least once a week.  The purpose is to have a recent copy on my machine, so I can develop against it.  It's not a backup for restoration purposes, so it does not have to be the latest are even exact.

1. Is there any **Windows** software that could run on my machine to do this?
2. Is it better to try some mysql **mirroring** scheme ?
3. Do I roll my own ?

Comment: Use MySQL Workbench, it is a UI program that also has the capability to create and import database dumps. If the database dump you have contains data and database structure then you can simply import it into a new empty database. You can also import it using MySQL command line tools but as you mentioned a Windows UI program Workbench my better suite your needs.

Comment: Probably better to write a bat script that does the transfer via ftp. You can then schedule it to run weekly using windows scheduler.